# Do I need transit visa for Dublin?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, ireland

I have a flight from BOM-MUC-DUB-YYZ. In DUB, the flight will land at terminal 1. Will not be changing terminals because connecting flight is from same terminal.

Can you please tell whether I need transit visa?

The website isn't clear about this part. The airlines said i need to confirm from embassy.

Traveller holds Indian passport.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Irish Department of Justice and Equality provides [a page where you can check the requirements](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/check-irish-visa).

By entering the details you provided in your question (Indian citizen, transiting in Ireland) you reach [this page](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-required-transit). The headline "You do not need a transit visa" is unfortunately misleading in your case, as the page lists further conditions which apply to transfers at Dublin airport.

> Transit passengers making connections at Dublin Airport should be aware of the following:-
>
> - You should check to see if you need a Visa/transit Visa before travelling and apply if required
> - In all circumstances you will present to an immigration officer.
> - Unless your arrival flight is in Terminal 2 between the hours of 0400 and 1600, you will need to go landside to make your onward connecting flight. This requires that you seek permission to enter the State (you will need to have the appropriate Irish entry visa if you are visa required for entry to Ireland).

Specifically the third bullet point is relevant for your friend - if her flight to Dublin lands at Terminal 1, she will have to seek permission to enter Ireland. That means she will require an **entry visa** for Ireland (**not** a transit visa).

Answer (score 7):

The airline is perfectly capable of telling you whether a visa is needed in this scenario; they have a shared database called Timatic which is used for this purpose, and they use it to verify your documents when you check in for your flight. It's not clear why they refused to tell you over the phone, but I can make some uncharitable guesses.

Anyway, regarding transiting through Dublin airport, Timatic says you can only do it without a visa in Terminal 2.

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through Dublin
>   (DUB) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
>   country. They must:
>
> - arrive at and depart from Terminal 2, and
> - be transiting between 04:00 and 16:00 on the same calendar
>     day, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.

Answer (score 3):

The visa was not required at all. The airport visa checking officer understood the issue and let the person pass without any issue.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to tell us your experience. Could you clarify, did you contact the Irish embassy before the flight, and they advised you that you didn't need a visa?

Comment: Naah. Simply boarded the flight. There they raised the concern but didn't do anything and simply allowed to travel ahead.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "The Embassy" then?

Comment: "The visa was not required at all". I think it is important to mention that a visa is required but the officer in this case used his or her discretion to allow the traveller to proceed to her next flight. Other travellers without a visa may not necessarily have the same outcome.